# convertir un array proveniente de un campo array de postgres a array javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un campo de tipo `array` en una tabla en `postgres` ahora necesito tener este array de postgres en un array javascript;

recibo lo siguiente del backend:

```
{three,tow,one}
```

con la siguiente función remplazo las llaves `{}`;

```
....
postgresArray = postgresArray .replace("{", "[");
postgresArray = postgresArray .replace("}", "]");

console.log(postgresArray);
```

Pero el problema es obvio, no es un array literal de javascript, necesito tenerlo de la siguiente manera;

```
["three","tow","one"]
```

Comment: Me parece que el problema está más en cómo lo envía el backend a tu front end. En lugar de enviar una cadena podría enviar el arreglo como tal. Si no es posible, aquí hay una librería que cubre la mayor parte de los casos: https://github.com/bendrucker/postgres-array/blob/master/index.js

Comment: @rvazquezglez Muchas gracias! le hechare un vistazo a la librería.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He encontrado la solución mas rápido de lo que pensé;

Lo primero que hice fue remover las llaves en vez de agregar corchetes `[]`;

```
let postgresArray = '{there,tow,one}'
postgresArray = postgresArray .replace("{", "");
postgresArray = postgresArray .replace("}", "");

console.log(postgresArray); //there,tow,one
```

Luego simplemente utilice `split`

```
console.log(checkboxArrayValues.split(',')); //(3) ["three", "tow", "one"]
```